# Complex json Data outputs "undefined" value

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-ajax

**I have Json data generated from two different classes in Asp.net MVC using the ajax. When I iterate that result to output the data it outputs as undefined. I have performed the following code to fetch the value**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btn_ffCalculate').on('click', function (evnt) {
            var plen = ($('#plinthLength').val() == "") ? 0 : $('#plinthLength').val();
            var pwid = ($('#plinthWidth').val() == "") ? 0 : $('#plinthWidth').val();
            var phgt = ($('#plinthHeight').val() == "") ? 0 : $('#plinthHeight').val();
            var dnsty = ($('#density').val() == "") ? 0 : $('#density').val();

            var dff1 = ($('#distnFromFloor1').val() == "") ? 0 : $('#distnFromFloor1').val();
            var dff2 = ($('#distnFromFloor2').val() == "") ? 0 : $('#distnFromFloor2').val();
            var dff3 = ($('#distnFromFloor3').val() == "") ? 0 : $('#distnFromFloor3').val();
            var dff4 = ($('#distnFromFloor4').val() == "") ? 0 : $('#distnFromFloor4').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'floatingFloorCalc',
                dataType: 'Json',
                data: {
                    , re63: $('#roomEffect63').val()
                    , re125: $('#roomEffect125').val()
                    , re250: $('#roomEffect250').val()
                    , re500: $('#roomEffect500').val()
                    , re1k: $('#roomEffect1k').val()
                    , re2k: $('#roomEffect2k').val()
                    , re4k: $('#roomEffect4k').val()
                    , re8k: $('#roomEffect8k').val()

                    , ncrid: $('#ncnrId').val()
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    var rspnse = $.parseJSON(data);
                    $.each(rspnse.GetTbic, function (tbicIndex, tbicValue) {                        
                        alert(tbicIndex + " : " + tbicValue.rmLen);
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Following is the json data generated by the code**

```
{  
    "GetTbic":{  
        "rmLen":1.0,
        "rmWid":1.0,
        "rmHgt":1.0,
        "totalRoomArea":64.56,
        "totalRoomAreaInFt":21.52,
        "roomVolInFt":35.31,
        "listAllCoefficeint":[  
            [  
                0.07,
                0.1,
                0.05,
                0.06,
                0.07,
                0.09,
                0.08,
                0.064
            ],
            [  
                0.126,
                0.18,
                0.06,
                0.04,
                0.03,
                0.02,
                0.02,
                0.016
            ],
            [  
                1.0,
                1.0,
                1.0,
                1.0,
                1.0,
                1.0,
                1.0,
                1.0
            ]
        ],
        "listAreaCoefMulti":[  
            [  
                1.5064000000000002,
                2.152,
                1.076,
                1.2912,
                1.5064000000000002,
                1.9367999999999999,
                1.7216,
                1.37728
            ],
            [  
                2.71152,
                3.8735999999999997,
                1.2912,
                0.8608,
                0.6456,
                0.4304,
                0.4304,
                0.34432
            ],
            [  
                21.52,
                21.52,
                21.52,
                21.52,
                21.52,
                21.52,
                21.52,
                21.52
            ]
        ],
        "listAreaCoefSum":[  
            25.73792,
            27.5456,
            23.8872,
            23.672,
            23.672,
            23.8872,
            23.672,
            23.2416
        ],
        "listAirAbsorption":[  
            0.0,
            0.0,
            0.0,
            0.0,
            0.0,
            0.1,
            0.2,
            0.8
        ],
        "listRoomObsoprtion":[  
            25.73792,
            27.5456,
            23.8872,
            23.672,
            23.672,
            23.9872,
            23.872,
            24.0416
        ],
        "listRoomConstant":[  
            36.7,
            40.9,
            32.7,
            32.3,
            32.3,
            32.9,
            32.7,
            33.0
        ]
    },
    "Gettspl":{  
        "listSndPwrLvl":[  
            98.0,
            98.0,
            98.0,
            98.0,
            98.0,
            98.0,
            98.0,
            98.0
        ],
        "listCspl":[  
            103.0,
            103.0,
            103.0,
            103.0,
            103.0,
            103.0,
            103.0,
            103.0
        ],
        "listSplReduc":[  
            [  
                0.0,
                0.0,
                1.0,
                1.0,
                1.0,
                1.0,
                1.0,
                1.0
            ],
            [  
                0.0,
                0.0,
                1.0,
                1.0,
                1.0,
                1.0,
                1.0,
                1.0
            ],
            [  
                0.0,
                0.0,
                1.0,
                1.0,
                1.0,
                1.0,
                1.0,
                1.0
            ],
            [  
                0.0,
                0.0,
                1.0,
                1.0,
                1.0,
                1.0,
                1.0,
                1.0
            ]
        ],
        "listSwlSI":[  
            [  
                103.0,
                103.0,
                104.0,
                104.0,
                104.0,
                104.0,
                104.0,
                104.0
            ],
            [  
                103.0,
                103.0,
                104.0,
                104.0,
                104.0,
                104.0,
                104.0,
                104.0
            ],
            [  
                103.0,
                103.0,
                104.0,
                104.0,
                104.0,
                104.0,
                104.0,
                104.0
            ],
            [  
                103.0,
                103.0,
                104.0,
                104.0,
                104.0,
                104.0,
                104.0,
                104.0
            ]
        ],
        "listRsltFloorWidFF":[  
            59.0,
            56.0,
            54.0,
            47.0,
            41.0,
            34.0,
            29.0,
            25.0
        ],
        "listRsltntFloor":[  
            [  
                66.0,
                64.0,
                64.0,
                58.0,
                53.0,
                47.0,
                42.0,
                38.0
            ],
            [  
                66.0,
                64.0,
                64.0,
                58.0,
                53.0,
                47.0,
                42.0,
                38.0
            ],
            [  
                66.0,
                64.0,
                64.0,
                58.0,
                53.0,
                47.0,
                42.0,
                38.0
            ],
            [  
                66.0,
                64.0,
                64.0,
                58.0,
                53.0,
                47.0,
                42.0,
                38.0
            ]
        ],
        "listDeviatFF":[  
            12.0,
            20.0,
            25.0,
            25.0,
            24.0,
            20.0,
            17.0,
            14.0
        ],
        "listDeviFfAtMt":[  
            [  
                19.0,
                28.0,
                35.0,
                36.0,
                36.0,
                33.0,
                30.0,
                27.0
            ],
            [  
                19.0,
                28.0,
                35.0,
                36.0,
                36.0,
                33.0,
                30.0,
                27.0
            ],
            [  
                19.0,
                28.0,
                35.0,
                36.0,
                36.0,
                33.0,
                30.0,
                27.0
            ],
            [  
                19.0,
                28.0,
                35.0,
                36.0,
                36.0,
                33.0,
                30.0,
                27.0
            ]
        ],
        "listDeviatNoFloor":[  
            19.0,
            28.0,
            34.0,
            35.0,
            35.0,
            32.0,
            29.0,
            26.0
        ]
    }
}
```

***alert(tbicValue.rmLen);
should give 1 as output but output coming is "undefined"***

Comment: In jquery written, tbicvalue is value in ( index, value pair in $.each) iteration, but anyway it isn't working, nor does your suggestion did. I tried it.  Thank you!

Comment: Oh, I see. In that case it seems it should be `alert(tbicIndex + " : " + tbicValue);`, without the `rmLen`.

Comment: you were correct in suggestion, it was me who was making a mistake by adding the $.each() line which wasn't required. All I had to do was fetch the result as follows:

` success: function (data) {                    
                    var rspnse = $.parseJSON(data);
                    $('#rLen').text(rspnse.GetTbic.rmLen);`